# Replicate resource warnings

Tags: java, servlets, zk

How can I resolved these warnings during web application loading:

```
WARNING  Replicate resource: zkbind
Overwrite jar:file:<path-to>/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/zkbind-9.6.0.1.jar!/metainfo/zk/config.xml
with jar:file:<path-to>/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/zkbind-9.6.0.1.jar!/metainfo/zk/config.xml   [main] at org.zkoss.util.resource.ClassLocator.getDependentXMLResources()

WARNING  Replicate resource: zk
Overwrite jar:file:<path-to>/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/zk-9.6.0.1.jar!/metainfo/zk/config.xml
with jar:file:<path-to>/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/zk-9.6.0.1.jar!/metainfo/zk/config.xml   [main] at org.zkoss.util.resource.ClassLocator.getDependentXMLResources()

WARNING  Replicate resource: zul
Overwrite jar:file:<path-to>/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/zul-9.6.0.1.jar!/metainfo/zk/zk.xml
with jar:file:<path-to>/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/zul-9.6.0.1.jar!/metainfo/zk/zk.xml   [main] at org.zkoss.util.resource.ClassLocator.getDependentXMLResources()
```

The only ZK dependency I have is:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.zkoss.zk</groupId>
  <artifactId>zkbind</artifactId>
  <version>9.6.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Running with Jetty 9.4. No ZK related servlet mappings in web.xml - automatic configuration via zkwebfragment.jar

Maven dependency tree:

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ PROJECT ---
[INFO] <project-artifact>:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-jdk14:jar:1.7.30:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.30:compile
[INFO] +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-annotations:jar:9.4.30.v20200611:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-plus:jar:9.4.30.v20200611:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jndi:jar:9.4.30.v20200611:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:jar:9.4.30.v20200611:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:jar:9.4.30.v20200611:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-xml:jar:9.4.30.v20200611:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:jar:9.4.30.v20200611:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-security:jar:9.4.30.v20200611:compile
[INFO] |  |        \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:jar:9.4.30.v20200611:compile
[INFO] |  |           +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |           +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:jar:9.4.30.v20200611:compile
[INFO] |  |           \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:jar:9.4.30.v20200611:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:7.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:jar:7.3.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:jar:7.3.1:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.ow2.asm:asm-analysis:jar:7.3.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.zkoss.zk:zkbind:jar:9.6.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.zkoss.zk:zul:jar:9.6.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.zkoss.zk:zk:jar:9.6.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.zkoss.common:zweb:jar:9.6.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  \- org.zkoss.common:zcommon:jar:9.6.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     |     +- org.zkoss.common:zel:jar:9.6.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     |     \- org.apache-extras.beanshell:bsh:jar:2.0b6:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.zkoss.zk:zkwebfragment:jar:9.6.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  |        \- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.28.0-GA:compile
[INFO] +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:jar:1.60:compile
[INFO] +- com.h2database:h2:jar:1.3.170:compile
[INFO] +- org.jdom:jdom2:jar:2.0.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.json:json:jar:20180813:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.ant:ant-jsch:jar:1.10.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.ant:ant:jar:1.10.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.ant:ant-launcher:jar:1.10.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.jcraft:jsch:jar:0.1.55:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.sun:tools:jar:1.8.0:system
[INFO] +- com.ibm.icu:icu4j:jar:70.1:runtime
[INFO] \- junit:junit:jar:4.13:test
[INFO]    \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These messages usually mean that your application is importing multiple versions of the same files, or that each of these files in imported multiple times.
From the message in this case, it looks like you have identical files located in the same place or being overwritten by the same files.

In which context do you see these files? (IDE, building, running server, etc)
If you see these in your IDE (Eclipse?), you may have a project configuration issue, such as importing the same library folder twice through different path.

Additionally, the zkbind dependency will itself transitively load other ZK dependencies.
I'd recommend running a `mvn clean dependency:tree` command locally to see which dependencies are being added to your application, and from which parent.

Comment: I'm seeing it when running it as docker container. I agree that I must be doing a configuration mistake.

Comment: What is the context for these warnings? (console output from docker, console output from java servlet container insider docker, etc.)

Comment: I eventually [solved this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70433131/1124509) along with some other challenges.