# How to get ZK webfragment working with embedded Jetty 9?

Tags: java, jetty, embedded-jetty, zk

This minimal embedded Jetty project starts up correctly, scans for annotations and finds and maps the annotated TestServlet.

Project structure:

```
|-src/main/java/test
|  |-Test.java
|-webapp/
|  |-test.zul
|-pom.xml
```

Test.java:

```
package test;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.util.resource.Resource;
import org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.Configuration;
import org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.FragmentConfiguration;
import org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.MetaInfConfiguration;
import org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext;
import org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebInfConfiguration;
import org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Server server = new Server(8080);
        WebAppContext webapp = new WebAppContext();
        webapp.setContextPath("/test");
        webapp.setBaseResource(Resource.newResource(new File("webapp").getCanonicalFile()));
        // https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/jetty-9/index.html#configuring-webapps
        // the order is important
        webapp.setConfigurations(new Configuration[] { //
            new WebInfConfiguration(), //
            new WebXmlConfiguration(), //
            new MetaInfConfiguration(), //
            new FragmentConfiguration(), //
            // new EnvConfiguration(), // not needed
            // new PlusConfiguration(), // not needed
            new AnnotationConfiguration(), //
            // new JettyWebXmlConfiguration(), // no jetty-web.xml
        });
        webapp.setAttribute("org.eclipse.jetty.server.webapp.ContainerIncludeJarPattern", ".*");
        server.setHandler(webapp);
        server.setDumpAfterStart(true);
        server.start();
        java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI("http://localhost:8080/test/TestServlet")) /* working */;
        java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI("http://localhost:8080/test/test.zul")) /* not working */;
    }
    
    @WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/TestServlet"})
    public static final class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {
        @Override
        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
            resp.getWriter().write("Test 1");
        }
    }
}
```

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>9.4.30.v20200611</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.zkoss.zk</groupId>
            <artifactId>zkbind</artifactId>
            <version>9.6.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

test.zul:

```
<zk><label value="hello"/></zk>
```

The zk web fragment seems to be 'noted' somehow:

```
|  +@ org.eclipse.jetty.webFragments.cache = java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap@bb35baa5{size=30}
|  |  +@ file:///C:/Users/r.hoehener/.m2/repository/org/zkoss/common/zcommon/9.6.0.1/zcommon-9.6.0.1.jar = org.eclipse.jetty.util.resource.EmptyResource@3fc39309
|  |  +@ file:///C:/Users/r.hoehener/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-annotations/9.4.30.v20200611/jetty-annotations-9.4.30.v20200611.jar = org.eclipse.jetty.util.resource.EmptyResource@3fc39309
|  |  +@ file:///C:/Users/r.hoehener/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-io/9.4.30.v20200611/jetty-io-9.4.30.v20200611.jar = org.eclipse.jetty.util.resource.EmptyResource@3fc39309
|  |  +@ file:///C:/Users/r.hoehener/.m2/repository/org/apache-extras/beanshell/bsh/2.0b6/bsh-2.0b6.jar = org.eclipse.jetty.util.resource.EmptyResource@3fc39309
|  |  +@ file:///C:/Users/r.hoehener/.m2/repository/org/zkoss/zk/zkwebfragment/9.6.0.1/zkwebfragment-9.6.0.1.jar = jar:file:///C:/Users/r.hoehener/.m2/repository/org/zkoss/zk/zkwebfragment/9.6.0.1/zkwebfragment-9.6.0.1.jar!/META-INF/web-fragment.xml
...
```

But the test.zul is displayed as plain text. The ZK engine is not getting initialized.

Any ideas why?

Edit: In defense of the way I do the configuration: This is straight from the 9.x docs, which say 'You have a number of options for how to make Jetty use a different list of Configurations.', including 'Setting the list directly on the WebAppContext':

```
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
  <Set name="war"><SystemProperty name="jetty.base" default="."/>/webapps/my-cool-webapp</Set>
  <Set name="configurationClasses">
    <Array type="java.lang.String">
      <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebInfConfiguration</Item>
      <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration</Item>
      <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.MetaInfConfiguration</Item>
      <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.FragmentConfiguration</Item>
      <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.EnvConfiguration</Item>
      <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.PlusConfiguration</Item>
      <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration</Item>
      <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.JettyWebXmlConfiguration</Item>
    </Array>
  </Set>
</Configure>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, don't use Jetty 9.4.30, it's subject to a few security advisories now.

See: https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/security_reports.php

Use at least use Jetty 9.4.44.v20210927.

Next, check your Jetty Server dump for the zk servlets ...

- `org.zkoss.zk.au.http.DHtmlUpdateServlet`
- `org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.DHtmlLayoutServlet`

If those are present in your `WebAppContext` dump then your `zkwebfragment-<ver>.jar` was discovered and loaded by Jetty properly.  At this point, what you have left to do is how to properly configure for your zk lib using the zk techniques (you can ignore Jetty specific details from here on).

If they are not present, then first make sure your own webapp is using Servlet 3.0 (declared in your `WEB-INF/web.xml`) or newer for proper Web Fragment support (older Servlet specs don't support Web Fragment).

Next, make sure the `zkwebfragment-<ver>.jar` is present on the WebApp classloader, as no web-fragments will load from any other classloader per spec, not even the application / server / container classloaders.

If you still don't see them, then go back to adjusting the default `Configuration` list, not the hardcoded list you have in your code snippet.
(your list is missing required Configurations, and is in the wrong order for success, don't alter the default list, don't set the list on the webapp, only alter the server level defaults).

Ask yourself, what does zk require? (eg: if it needs jndi, then you need the jndi specific configuration piece too).

If you are not stuck on Java 8, please use Jetty 10, as the entire `Configuration` layer was reworked to no longer allow bad configurations (in fact the old `setConfiguration()` methods are not even there, just the existence of support jars is enough to flag that you want that support and enable it, in the right place, with the right parent dependencies).

Comment: Again, amazing answer, thank you very much! zkwebfragment is not present on the WebApp classloader (nothing is), so that's the reason why it's not working then. Leaves me (still) wondering about what a standard embedded Jetty deployment with ZK should look like.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer about the latest version. Currently I have to use Java 8 but no idea where that specific 9.4.x version came from.

Comment: In this minimal example there is no web.xml at all. I assume that in this case the Jetty libraries provide a default descriptor that supports Servlet 3.1?

Comment: Configuration: I followed the order in the docs closely and also cross-checked it with the default configuration order from the server dump. I left out the JettyWebXmlConfiguration because there is no jetty-web.xml. I also left out the JNDI configurations (not needed). I added the AnnotationConfiguration 'immediately before the JettyWebXmlConfiguration', as described in the docs.

Answer (score 2):

the way to add a configuration is:

```java
Configuration.ClassList classList = Configuration.ClassList.setServerDefault(server);
classList.addAfter(
                "org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.FragmentConfiguration",
                "org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration");
```

Update:

I have tried

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>10.0.7</version>
    </dependency>
```

The zul works without adding any configuration.

Comment: Thank you, but according to the docs, the way I did it is also correct. To me this way looks more random because the final order is less obvious. And you need to know exactly after or before what other existing configuration to add the AnnotationConfiguration anyway. For example, why did you add after the FragmentConfiguration, and not before the JettyWebXmlConfiguration? The docs say: 'The above configuration class (AnnotationConfiguration) must be inserted immediately before the org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.JettyWebXmlConfiguration class in the list of configurations.'

Comment: Regarding your update: I quickly tried with 10.0.7, but got 'Unable to load class org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.listener.ELContextCleaner'. Anyway, I tagged the question jetty-9 now, as I am stuck on Java 8 for now. Sorry about that.

Comment: @RetoHöhener the order is part of the definition of the `AnnotationConfiguration`, ie: it MUST be after `FragmentConfiguration`.   `FragmentConfiguration` is already in the right place per default definition.

Comment: Like I wrote in the comment, the wording in the docs is: 'The above configuration class (AnnotationConfiguration) must be inserted immediately before the org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.JettyWebXmlConfiguration class in the list of configurations.'. So I think it would be more natural to use `addBefore(JettyWebXml..., Annotation...)`

Answer (score 1):

So, as Joakim pointed out, the [Servlet Specification 3.1](https://javaee.github.io/servlet-spec/downloads/servlet-3.1/Final/servlet-3_1-final.pdf) says:

> If a framework wants its META-INF/web-fragment.xml honored in such a
> way that it augments a web application's web.xml, the framework must
> be bundled within the web application's WEB-INF/lib directory. [...] In other words, only JAR files bundled in a web
> application's WEB-INF/lib directory, but not those higher up in the
> class loading delegation chain, need to be scanned for
> web-fragment.xml

Therefore, I must ensure that `zkwebfragments.jar` is present on the WebAppContext's classpath.

I changed my deployment strategy to look like this:

```
/myapp/
  |-bin/
  |  |- project jar (including annotated servlets and listeners)
  |  |- all maven dependency jars (including jetty and zk libs)
  |-webapp/
  |  |-WEB-INF/
  |  |  |-lib/ (EMTPY!)
  |  |  |-web.xml
  |  |  |-zk.xml
  |  |-index.zul
  |  |-other static resources
  |-data/
     |-application data (docker mounted host volume)
```

In the main class, adding the zkwebfragment.jar to the WebAppContext classpath:

```
Server server = new Server(port);
WebAppContext webapp = new WebAppContext();
webapp.setContextPath("/myapp");
webapp.setBaseResource(Resource.newResource(new File(isDocker ? "/myapp/webapp" : "./webapp").getCanonicalFile()));
// order important: https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/jetty-9/index.html#configuring-webapps
webapp.setConfigurations(new Configuration[] { //
    new WebInfConfiguration(), //
    new WebXmlConfiguration(), //
    new MetaInfConfiguration(), //
    new FragmentConfiguration(), //
    new AnnotationConfiguration(), //
});
// servlet spec: fragments are only loaded if they are bundled in WEB-INF/lib
webapp.setExtraClasspath(Arrays.asList(((URLClassLoader) MyAppMain.class.getClassLoader()).getURLs()).stream().filter(
    u -> u.toString().contains("zkwebfragment")).findAny().get().toString());
// scan for annotations in the container classpath (AppClassLoader)
webapp.setAttribute("org.eclipse.jetty.server.webapp.ContainerIncludeJarPattern", ".*");
server.setHandler(webapp);
server.setDumpAfterStart(true);
server.start();
```

When running the main class from an IDE, all project classes and all maven dependencies are automatically added to the AppClassLoader.

When running as docker container, the application is started with:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-cp", "/myapp/bin/*", "myapp.MyAppMain"]
```

which also adds the project jar and all maven dependency jars to the AppClassLoader.

By moving all jars out of `/myapp/webapp/META-INF/lib/*` to `/myapp/bin/*`, all jars exist only once in the classloader hierarchy, which also solves the [ZK replicate resources warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70415779/replicate-resource-warnings). Except for the `zkwebfragment.jar`, which exists twice. Jetty dump excerpts:

```
| |  +> WebAppClassLoader{1509563803}@59fa1d9b
| |  |  +> URLs size=1
| |  |  |  +> file:/myapp/bin/zkwebfragment-9.6.0.1.jar
| |  |  +> sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@2ff4acd0
```

and further down:

```
| +> sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@2ff4acd0
|    +> URLs size=52
|    |  +> file:/myapp/bin/myapp.jar
|    |  +> file:/myapp/bin/jetty-annotations-9.4.44.v20210927.jar
|    |  +> file:/myapp/bin/zkwebfragment-9.6.0.1.jar
|    |  +> ...
|    +> sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader@4ee285c6
|       +> URLs size=9
|          +> file:/opt/java/openjdk/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar
|          +> ...
```

None of this would be necessary if I were using a Jetty installation and dropping my application bundled as a standard WAR. But I really wanted to try out this plain Java approach (from the Jetty docs):

> Jetty has a slogan, "Don’t deploy your application in Jetty, deploy
> Jetty in your application!" What this means is that as an alternative
> to bundling your application as a standard WAR to be deployed in
> Jetty, Jetty is designed to be a software component that can be
> instantiated and used in a Java program just like any POJO.

Comment: You can get away with a lot with embedded Jetty, but you typically don't want to mix all of the rules of WAR and the Servlet Spec, including auto-discovery, with embedded jetty as they are quite complex.  Most embedded Jetty users use `ServletContextHandler` and programattically defined/assigned Servlets with no auto-discovery.

Comment: Do yourself a favor, decide on a packaging technique for your project now, embedded or proper war.  If you go embedded, use `ServletContextHandler` (skip the classloader mess, the webapp initialization mess, the auto-discovery mess, etc).  If you go war, then embrace it fully!  don't have your embedded jetty server code have build time dependencies on anything other than Jetty and things you need for the server itself (be careful to not include the war as a dependency with it's dependencies, as that messes up your classloader greatly)

Comment: It's even possible to create an executable war with embedded jetty, where you can just use `java -jar /path/to/my-app.war` to execute it.  See https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-live-war/blob/jetty-10.0.x/theserver/pom.xml  (note: there are branches for Jetty 9, Jetty 10, and Jetty 11, so use the example that best fits you)

Comment: Yes, I have used (only) programmatically defined Servlets in embedded Jetty in the past as well (very nice and clean). Here I am taking over a 10+ year old project, and I cannot easily get rid of the ZK framework dependency. Actually I am quite happy how this turned out :) Adding that ZK web fragment jar to the WebAppContext classpath is the only remaining hack. I can live with that. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Another problem I'm trying to tackle is that people often do not check in their local test server configurations (Tomcat, Jetty...). Or people have different IDE's, with different server support. So people are very reluctant to touch the project, because the effort required just to get it to launch is too big. With an embedded Jetty project, all they have to do is run a main class. No additional Jetty or IDE know-how necessary to get started :)